# SQL spread column GROUP into a single row without multiple JOIN

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, row

How can I show the grouped column into a single row to make it visually clear with the count value? I think there must be a concise way instead of joining multiple table to show a single row.

My table (tb) looks like this

```
Name      Subjects
David     Geography
David     Geography
Sherry    History
Paul      History
Paul       Math
Ken       Chemistry
```

I want to show the table like this

```
Name    Geography    History     Math     Chemistry   Total
David   2            0           0        0           2
Sherry  0            2           0        0           2
Paul    0            1           1        0           2
Ken     0            0           0        1           1
```

I'm doing like multiple join tables

```
SELECT g.name, g.count, h.count, m.count, c.count, 
g.count + h.count + m.count + c.count as Total
FROM
(SELECT name, count(*) as count
FROM tb 
WHERE Subjects = "Geography"
GROUP BY Name) as g
JOIN
(SELECT name, count(*) as count
FROM tb
WHERE Subjects = "History"
GROUP BY Name) as h
ON g.name = h.name
JOIN 
(SELECT name, count(*) as count
FROM tb
WHERE Subjects = "Math"
GROUP BY Name) as m
ON g.name = m.name
JOIN
(SELECT name, count(*) as count
FROM tb
WHERE Subjects = "Chemistry"
GROUP BY Name) as c
ON g.name = c.name
```

Comment: Perhaps you didn't even know what to search for, but a search for "pivot table SQL" would have turned up a lot of help.

Comment: Great! I'll check "pivot table SQL" tutorial. I know a bit of SQL basics. Not really an expert. Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT Name, COUNT(CASE WHEN Subjects = 'Geography' THEN 1 END) AS Geography ... GROUP BY Name` ... then add case expressions for the other subjects as well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen pretty neat with CASE WHEN. It's the key word that I don't know "Pivot Table" to begin with. Thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, BigQuery. I updated the tags.

Comment: @Kenneth - does referenced answer applicable to your case? if no - why. I am asking because this was mark as a duplicated for mySQL butt hen you  added and clarified that it is for BigQuery

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant, CASE WHEN also works in BigQuery either in #standardSQL or #--use_legacy_sql=false as well.

Comment: sure i am aware of this :o) just wanted to double check if your got this. so, looks like you are good here. great!